# Adjust font and picture size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a web page, the full screen snapshot in a desktop likes. The menu has some Asian fonts, don't worry about it.

[image: image1]

The html:

```
<header>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("主页", "Index", "Home")</li> // asp.net mvc link
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("关于教会", "About", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("联系方式", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("主日证道", "Sermon", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("教会活动", "Activity", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("社区服务", "Community", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

The corresponding css:

```
.nav {
float: left;
}
/* menu
 ----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul.menu {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
 }

 ul.menu li {
    border: 1px solid #FF9933;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
 }

    ul.menu li a {
        background: none;
        color: #336699;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        ul.menu li a:hover {
            color: #333;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

 header {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 8px;
    background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    color: #336699;
    padding: 20px 40px 30px 40px;
  }
```

Once I zoom it to a medium size, the image became:
[image: image2]

You see the menu is not huddled together, I think that because the font size is fixed. How to adjust it accordingly? Is it the responsive web design? I just heard this term.

And also please notice the image's size is fixed say 500x400, can it be adjusted as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) come into play, in your css you set the thresholds/breakpoints and apply different styling accordingly

For example :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 599px) {
.menu_font
{
font-size:10px; /* set the size as you see fit*/
}
}
```

==Edit to make more sense==

```
/* menu
 ----------------------------------------------------------*/
 @media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 599px) {
ul.menu {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean I have to create different css files and switch them by different media?

Comment: no you simply include these in your css with the min-max width parameters, simply resize your browser and check @ what width the design breaks, the style you define in between the media query will only be applied when the screen width range is true, that way you don't need to use different style sheets. @Love

Comment: And the items in the curly brackets are media names? Is it the requirement of the syntax? ul.menu font or .menu_font in css?

Comment: @Love they are css classes, the exact same classes you are using for your current css except you change the parameters in them for example instead of  font-size: 1em; for ul.menu in the query you put font-size:0.75em;